# Can I modify the logic for value redistribution in pie chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, pie-chart, lightningchart

In LightningchartJS Pie chart can we change the logic for value redistribution. For example, consider the chart in image 1. If I hide a certain region say Planning, then the percentage of values is equally distributed in all the other regions see image 2. Is there a way in which I can customise this distribution of values?

[image: Pie Chart 1]

[image: Pie Chart 2]

Answer (score 3):

You can customize the labels by using the .setLabelFormatter() method.

You can check the [Slice LabelFormatter](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.1.0/globals.html#slicelabelformatter) from the [LightningChart JS API documentation](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.1.0/index.html) for an example on how to use a custom implementation.

**Distributing values of hidden slices**

If you want to instead redistribute the value of a hidden slice, it is possible but trickier as Pie Chart does not have this feature natively.

This can be done by adding the desired functionality to the legendBox's buttons instead.

After creating the legendBox, you can add specific slices instead of adding the whole PieChart, then modify the behavior when clicking on each entry.

```js
// Add a legendBox UI element
const legendBox = chart.addLegendBox()

// Add the slices to the legendBox separately, so we can use custom behavior when clicking on the entries
const entry = legendBox.add( slice1 )

entry.onSwitch((_, state) => {
  // If the entry's state is true after clicking, restore everything to normal
  if(state) {
    slice1.restore()
    slice2.setValue(120)
  // Else, hide the slice the entry is linked to, and distribute its value to another slice
  } else {
    slice1.dispose()
    slice2.setValue(160)
  }
}
```

Comment: No. I am not talking about, formatting of labels. but about slice area distribution. meaning the all slice area get distributed equally when one slice is removed. Can we change that logic for custom distribution percentage or value? I hope i am explaining it well.

Comment: Added a simple example on how to modify the legendBox and chart with the behavior you described to my answer. Hope this answers your question.